# Does Postgres support stored column labels that can be queried?

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.3

I'm not a DBA but seem to recall that there was a SQL database that stored column labels (preferred column headings that can be printed on reports). Does Postgres support labels such as these?

Comment: [The name of the RDBMS is `PostgreSQL`, or `Postgres` for short, or `pg` for very short.](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) Ain't no such thing as "Postgre".

Answer (score 2):

You might be refereing to catalog level comments, which can be used to get a description of any table and or column in the database.

Those are created using:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE yourtable IS 'A good description';
COMMENT ON COLUMN yourtable.yourcolumn IS 'Column desc';
```

To query those, you can use this kind of query:

```
SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name,pgd.description
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
inner join pg_catalog.pg_description pgd on (pgd.objoid=st.relid)
inner join information_schema.columns c on (pgd.objsubid=c.ordinal_position
and  c.table_schema=st.schemaname and c.table_name=st.relname)
where table_name = 'yourtablename'
```

Beware however that this cannot be localized.

Answer (score 1):

No. (You may be thinking of MS Access.)

But you can easily substitute with a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html). Like in *almost any* RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that the labels could be read along with the column values to maintain label consistency.